# Zend Form element default value empty

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have an Zend Form extended from `Zend_Dojo_Form` there are some input element added with `$this->addElement('text','email')`. In controller i prepopulate form field with

```
$myForm = new MyForm();
$this->view->myForm = $myForm;
$this->view->unsubscribeForm->email->setValue('abc@def');
$this->view->unsubscribeForm->email->setAttrib('whereismyvalue','missing');
```

And in view script, i use this to display

```
<?php echo $this->unsubscribeForm ?>
```

But when it is render the field value is missing

```
<input id="email" type="text" whereismyvalue="missing" value="" name="email">
```

even when I try

```
$this->view->unsubscribeForm->email->setAttrib('value','beep');
```

Nothing show up, and I dont know why :(

Comment: It works very well for me. Maybe you have a populate with email's value =''?

Comment: No, it always goes empty "", I can set any attribute i want but not value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you check **everytime** if `$form->isValid()` before `echo $this->form`. That's a mistake. Make sure first that it is a **post request and then check the form**.

In fact `$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost();)` reset every value in the form if they are not valid!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->view->myForm->getElement('email')->setValue('abc@def');
$this->view->myForm->getElement('email')->setAttrib('value','beep');
```

Comment: Thank for your reply but it still empty :( >"<

Comment: I can set everything else (attribute) but not the value

Comment: No, still no luck, I got this project from someone else. The value seem to be rip off somewhere else. I can set every attribute else but the value one. Can you suggest how can i trace this?

Comment: Check your code if the value is replacing from somewhere else after setting the value. Check your php code and java script also if you have.